# Twitter API - api.search_users(q)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using the below to search for any users who's names end in **.btc**

The issue I have is it seems to be searching for any accounts with BTC in the username or screenname and the search doesn't also recognise the full stop.

Is there a way to make this field to only search for exact matches?

I also understand api.search_users(q) has a 1000 limit and wondering how to retrieve the full list as its only returning 20.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

***Code***

```
# import the module
import tweepy
  
# assign the values accordingly
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
  
# authorization of consumer key and consumer secret
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
  
# set access to user's access key and access secret 
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# calling the api 
api = tweepy.API(auth)
  
# the query to be searched
q = ".BTC"

# search the query
users = api.search_users(q)
  
# print the users retrieved
for user in users:
    print(user.name),print(user.screen_name)
```

*****Current results*****

```
BTC Times
btc
BTC Bahamas
BTC242
Bitcoin Foundation
BTCFoundation
Documenting Bitcoin 
DocumentingBTC
Crypto Tiger
CryptoTigerBtc
GoWestBTC
NiftyReport
BTC Market Alert
btc_orderalert
BTC Sessions 
BTCsessions
Bitcoin Archive 
BTC_Archive
BTC Status Alert 
btc_status
Interlay #interBTC
InterlayHQ
Depression BTC
depression2019
Charlie
btc_charlie
AngeloƉOGE
AngeloBTC
Bitcoin Alert!
btc_alert
//Bitcoin ack 
BTC_JackSparrow
Bitcoin News
BTCNewsletter
stacks.btc
Stacks
AlphaBTC
mark_cullen
muneeb.btc
muneeb
```

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value for the `count` argument of `search_users` is 20, so you can't retrieve more than 20 users per request and you have to use pagination if you want more (up to 1000).

Tweepy handles it easily with a `Cursor` object:

```py
cursor = tweepy.Cursor(
    api.search_users,              # The method you want to use
    ".btc",                        # Your argument(s) for this method
    count=20                       # Number of users to retrieve per request
)

for user in cursor.items(1000):    # Total number of users to retrieve
    print(user)                    # Check here if user name ends with .btc
```

You can read more about Cursor in the Tweepy documentation ([here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v1_pagination.html)).

And as far as I know, there is no way to improve your search with the Twitter API.